# How to connect Python Selenium with Electron JS App

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm building a simple automation app that will use Electron JS for good GUI and then Python Selenium to automate the task.

I've just started when I'm trying to run electron JS app it shows that there is no module named as selenium.

### Here is my python (demo.py)

```
    import time
    import re
    from selenium import webdriver
    import webbrowser
    import sys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    
    browser.get('https://example.com')
    
    userid = browser.find_element_by_id('user')
    time.sleep(1)
    userpass = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
    time.sleep(1)
    userid.send_keys('aafasdf@gmail.com')
    time.sleep(1)
    userpass.send_keys('#jlasdjf#')
    
    
    time.sleep(1)
    userid.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    userid.clear()
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Hello from Python!')
    sys.stdout.flush()

And the goes my index.js file
-
function some(){

    var ps = require("python-shell")
    var path = require("path")

    var options = {
        scriptPath : path.join(__dirname,'../seleniumBro/'),
        pythonPath : '/usr/local/bin/python3.8'
    }
 
    ps.PythonShell.run('../../seleniumBro/demo.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // swal(results[0]);
        console.log(results[0])
      });
    
    

}
```

[image]

When I run the app I get this error in console.

```
index.js:12 Uncaught Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
    at PythonShell.parseError (/Users/rahul/Desktop/justDev/electronBro/hello-world/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:258:21)
    at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/rahul/Desktop/justDev/electronBro/hello-world/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:141:32)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/rahul/Desktop/justDev/electronBro/hello-world/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:133:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "/Users/rahul/Desktop/justDev/seleniumBro/demo.py", line 3, in <module>
      from selenium import webdriver
```

I'm on MAC OS. And also new to this. Please help.

Comment: FYI, selenium is available for node too. Otherwise you need to somehow distribute python with your electron app.

Comment: @pguardiaro Hey thanks for the information.

I've two questions:
1: Instead of Python I should use Node JS?
2: And can I do same automation with Node JS Selenium?

Comment: It's pretty much the same but more awaits. Another idea is to switch from electron to flask, if you're more comfortable with Python this is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm new to both electron and Python, and even can learn Node.Js. I hope this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my views. You should go with Node.js as said by pguardio that Selenium is available for node too.